# How to retrieve GOPATH from Docker container?

Tags: go, docker, text-editor

My objective is to have a self contained Go Workspace per project.

Is it possible to retrieve a Go workspace and Go environment variables from a running Docker container to be used by an IDE or Text Editor for development?

I have already tried mapping a volume to the container with the go tools and dependencies. But that requires always setting the GOPATH to the current workspace, and requires to have the go tools and dependencies on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at least [set and pass those environment variable when launching your container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables):

```
docker run -e "GOPATH=/a/mounted/path" -v [host-src:]container-dest --rm -it <yourImage>
```

By using `-v`, you allow your host to share a folder with your container.

Comment: How about having container's path that is not a volume? Is it possible?

Comment: @sargas sure: in that case, GOPATH is set to a path which is managed and visible only from within that container.

Comment: @sargas in that case, it is easier to set it in the .bashrc of the default user in that container, if said path won't change.

Comment: @sargas by container's path, do you mean the GOPATH path you want to set within that container?

Comment: Yes. And the idea is to have that container GOPATH passed to a text editor in the host for development: auto completion, linting, etc. Sorry if I'm being vague. I want to describe what I want as clear as possible.

Comment: @sargas if you want to edit from the host, then you need an host volume: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems

Comment: I see. Does your answer need a flag to mount a volume?

Comment: @sargas I have edited the answer 14 minutes ago to add that flag.