# How can I configure go sdk and GOPATH from docker container?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, goland, gopath

I'm trying to configure golang project with Jetbrains Gogland and docker compose. I want to use GOPATH and go from the docker container. I mean using the go installation from the container for the autocomplete etc without installing golang on the local machine.
the project structure is:

```
project root
    docker-compose.yml
    back|
         Dockerfile
         main.go
         some other packages
    front|
         all the front files...
```

After that, I want to deploy my `back` folder to the `/go/src/app` in the docker container. The problem is that when I develop the project I can''t use autocomplete as this project is not in my local GOPATH and there are different golang versions in the docker container and on my local machine
I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687929/how-to-retrieve-gopath-from-docker-container) question but I still can't solve my issue.

Comment: Do you want to access `Go` SDK in your local machine from `Docker` container?

Comment: @Arpit Yes, go sdk and go path

Comment: @Arpit thanks for your comment. But how can I take a go SDK link to add it in the goglang settings. '-v' it's a volumes part in the docker-compose file?

Comment: I'm just curious, what is the use-case for this? Why would you want to have the sources and Go only in containers?

Comment: @dlsniper maybe it's just because I don't have yet another docker skill and I try to invent a bicycle. This way can solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible. Nor do I see how it could be possible in the future. Mounting a volume in docker means you "hide" the contents of that folder from the container and use the files on the host instead. As such, any time you'll mount the directory from your machine, your container files from that instance won't be available to the machine. This means you can't have Go installed in the container and then mount a folder and use that location for the Go sources. If you are thinking: I'll just mount things in another place, do some symlink magic / copy files around, that's just a bad idea that leads to nowhere.

Gogland supports remote debugging as of EAP 10, released a a few weeks ago. This allows you to debug applications running in containers or on remote hosts. As such, you can install Go, and the source code on your machine but have them running in containers.

Comment: This is true, but docker also allows data to be copied from a [container into a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container).

It's then possible to share this data between containers/services using named volumes in docker-compose v3 or volumes_from in docker-compose v2.

If docker-compose expanded the mechanism to allow you bind a host directory to this volume much like how services can mount this populated data volume, it would satisfy what the OP wants.

Comment: We technically can already do this by creating a volume from the golang container specifying /go so the volume is then populated with the go binaries. After that we would then find the mountpoint on the host and symlink from there, but as you hinted, it's messy to deal with.